# How can I pass multiple routes as arguments to the Route::is() method in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel 8 application. I need to use `Route::is` for multiple routes, like this

```
@if(Route::is('user') or Route::is('register') or Route::is('login'))
    Do something
@endif
```

#### The goal

I want to **shorten this syntax** so I tried to pass the routes as arguments to the `Route::is()` method:

```
@if(Route::is('user,register,login'))
    Do something
@endif
```

#### The problem

The above method does not work.

###### Is there an alternative, working way to pass multiple routes as arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that as shown below

```
@if(request()->routeIs(['user','register','login']))
   Do something
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Even easier way:

```php
@if(request()->routeIs('user','register','login'))
   Do something
@endif
```